# Weird Java Error [JUnit Test]

Tags: java

I am running a method that returns a boolean. The method does not change any data. The first line returns false but then when I run the assertion test it says that it is returning null. Any thoughts?

```
System.out.println(fb.existsInNetwork(x)); // returns false
assertFalse(fb.existsInNetwork(x)); // junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null
```

Comment: Post the actual output of the test as well, please, so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

we know that if a method returns a boolean, it cannot return null.  I suspect that instead you should interpret this as "Assertion failed, and the message is: null".  Try instead calling the version of `assertFalse` which takes a message:

```
assertFalse("didn't expect x to be in network", fb.existsInNetwork(x))
```